# Bootstrap Row, add a Google Map-Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a script with map-canvas ID and it just won't show in a Bootstrap row with custom CSS against of #map-canvas, can anyone help me??

**CSS**

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>;
```

My **Javascript**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Fishtrends.com - 2013 - Tight Lines</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    var marker;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.559322, -4.174804);
      var options = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
      var html = "<table>" +
                 "<tr><td>Username:</td> <td><input type='text' id='userid'/> </td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Fish Species:</td> <td><select id='fishspecies'>" +
                         "<option value='Bass' SELECTED>Bass</option>" +
                         "<option value='Cod'>Cod</option>" +
                         "<option value='Gurnard'>Gurnard</option>" +           
                         "<option value='Flatty'>Flatty</option>" +
                         "<option value='Mackeral'>Mackeral</option>" +
                         "<option value='Whiting'>Whiting</option>" +
                         "<option value='Pollack'>Pollack</option>" +
                         "<option value='Wrasse'>Wrasse</option>" +
                         "<option value='Garfish'>Garfish</option>" +
                 "<option value='Blank'>Blank</option>" +                            
                 "<tr><td>Catch Method:</td> <td><select id='catchmethod'>" +
                         "<option value='Beach' SELECTED>Beach</option>" +
                         "<option value='Boat'>Boat</option>" +
                         "<option value='Spinning'>Spinning</option>" +
                 "<option value='Pier'>Pier</option>" +

                 "<tr><td>Bait:</td> <td><select id='bait'>" +
                         "<option value='Lugworm' SELECTED>Lugworm</option>" +
                         "<option value='Mackerel'>Makerel</option>" +
                         "<option value='Ragworm' >Ragworm</option>" +
                         "<option value='Livebait'>Livebait</option>" +
                         "<option value='Squid'>Squid</option>" +
                         "<option value='Peeler'>Peeler</option>" +

                 "<tr><td>Size LB:</td> <td><input type='text' id='sizelb'/> </td> </tr>" +              
                 "<tr><td>Month Caught:</td> <td><select id='month'>" +
                         "<option value='January' SELECTED>January</option>" +
                         "<option value='February'>February</option>" +
                         "<option value='March'>March</option>" +           
                         "<option value='April'>April</option>" +
                         "<option value='May'>May</option>" +
                         "<option value='June'>June</option>" +
                         "<option value='July'>July</option>" +
                         "<option value='August'>August</option>" +
                         "<option value='September'>September</option>" +
                 "<option value='October'>October</option>" +
                 "<option value='November'>November</option>" +
                 "<option value='December'>December</option>" + 
                 "</select> </td></tr>" +
                 "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });


    });
    }
    function saveData() {
      var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
      var fishspecies = escape(document.getElementById("fishspecies").value);

      var catchmethod = escape(document.getElementById("catchmethod").value);
      var bait = document.getElementById("bait").value;

      var sizelb = document.getElementById("sizelb").value;
      var month = document.getElementById("month").value;

      var latlng = marker.getPosition();              
     var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?fishspecies=" + fishspecies + "&catchmethod=" + catchmethod + "&bait=" + bait + "&month=" + month + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng() + "&sizelb=" + sizelb + "&userid=" + userid;
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Fish added"
        }
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    </script>
```

Comment: please put a working examplpe of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/sVhqU/

Comment: your example does not work because initialize function is never called and the request to your local script phpsqlinfo_addrow.php can not be made succesfully

Comment: Interesting, so is the Initialize function the reason it doesn't appear? the php script I can reference eventually properly...

Comment: Can anyone help? This is driving me up the wall....

Comment: as Jason said, you should tell google which is the init function. You should learn to debug javascript in order to tell which function with what parameters is called using console.log("whatever you want") inside functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Emil on the lack of something to kick off the initialise function:
Take a look here at the [simple map example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

At the bottom of the javascript section is:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

which is a function built into the Google maps API.
See if adding that line helps.

Comment: Hi Jason, Yes strange, however whats weird is the map loads with script in a standard HTML file. I'm just reading a bit into this. I struggle to understand orientation in code as i'm a noob :)

Comment: I think i've been using the incorrect API for Maps also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/mmlugLgmSFo I think i'm working it out slowly :) Next thing I need to "understand" is if my code is based on the v2 or v3 api :(

Comment: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>` is the right script for version 3 - as copied from the Google Maps Simple map example above.

Comment: See if you can get a simple example working in jsbin.com, and I'll take a look for you.